# How to use the Query and Import Range in Google Sheets with a Date Criteria?

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two separate workbooks, I would like to bring over the date value found in column E as long as it's not a null value. The formula below brings over the first value found in the range you see below but nothing else and I can't figure out why. I should have about 2400 values being brought over.

```
=query({importrange("workbookadress","Sheet1!E2:E3000")},"Where Col1 >='01/01/1900'",1)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=query({importrange("workbookadress","Sheet1!E2:E3000")},"Where Col1 >= date '1900-01-01' ",1)`

`Col1 >= date '1900-01-01'` is the notation (yyyy-mm-dd).

If you want to get the date from a cell value, then you'd need to use:

`Col1 >= date 'xxx'` where xxx is:

`"&text(Z1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"` where `Z1` is your cell.

Comment: Thanks for the help but more importantly the explanation.

Comment: Happy to help. If the start of your range `E2` is not a heading, change the end of the query from `,1)` to `,0)`. This will then treat `E2` as a data value. Alternatively, set the range from `E1:E3000`.